# Ajax result as an img?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This script is pulling an img link, which works fine so far, but I have no Idea how to return the link as an img.. Somebody help me!

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
            var channel_name = 'justsmoki';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + channel_name,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json',
                success: function(json_result) {
                    $('#my_stream_logo').html(json_result.logo);
                }
            });
        </script>

<span id="my_stream_logo"></span>
```

Comment: switch the success with this

success: function(json_result) {
                    $('#my_stream_logo').html(<'img src='+json_result.logo+'/>');
                }

Comment: The result you get back from a request is a string, not an object, you need to parse it to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var channel_name = 'justsmoki';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + channel_name,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json',
                success: function(json_result) {
                    $('#img').attr("src",json_result.logo);

                }
            });
```

Change `span` to `img`.

```
<img id="img" />
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmz490y7/).

Answer (score -1):

In your success callback, you want to set the html of your element.
Replace this...

```
success: function(json_result) {
  $('#my_stream_logo').html(json_result.logo);
}
```

With this...

```
success: function(json_result) {
  $('#my_stream_logo').html("<img src='"+json_result.logo+"'>")
}
```